# Why Magento 2 language switcher doesn't change store view?

Tags: php, html, magento2

I'm using Magento 2.2.6 with porto theme.

My store has three store views: en, it, fr.

For en and it there aren't problems, but for fr when I try to change language sometimes it doesn't work and append '#' to URL.

Here is my code for language switcher:

```php
<a href="#" 
  data-post='<?php echo $this->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>' 
  style="padding-right: 1px; padding-left: 2px; border-left: 0">
  <?php if($_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/header/language_flag')): ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $_helper->getBaseUrl().'wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/flags/'.$block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()).'.jpg'; ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Is there someone who can help me ?
Thanks in advance !